# java keep checking on the original array in the constructor after I add an element to the reference array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I used 2D array to create a sudokuPuzzle game, but after the user enters a value, compiler keep checking on the original array in the constructor!

```
public void addInitial(int row, int column, int value) {

    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

        if (board[i][column] == value || board[row][i] == value || board[row][column] != 0) {
            //first condition to check the place itself. Second condition to check the rows, third for columns. fourth to check if the given row and column is a blank space (0)
            //not solved correctly yet
            System.out.println("Wrong value, try again!");
            break;

        }
        if (board[i][column] != value || board[row][i] != value || board[row][column] == 0) {
            board[row][column] = value;
            System.out.println(value + " has been added");

            break;
        }
    }
}


public class Sudoku {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        SudokuPuzzle game = new SudokuPuzzle();
        int i = 0;
        do{
            System.out.println(game);
            i++;
            System.out.println("Enter row, column, and value");
            System.out.print("Row: ");
            int r = input.nextInt() - 1;
            System.out.print("Column: ");
            int c = input.nextInt() - 1;
            System.out.print("Value: ");
            int v = input.nextInt();
            game.addInitial(r, c, v);

        }while(i < 3); // the loop is just to try 3 values
    }
}
```

I dont want the user to enter two same values above each other or next to each other, but compiler allow that because it keep checking on the original array in the constructor.

Comment: *`"compiler keep checking on the original array in the constructor!"`* What does this mean? What original `Array`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with original array - but this line doesn't check whether you have added a value already in s roe or column - better write it out on paper `if (board[i][column] != value || board[row][i] != value || board[row][column] == 0) {`

Comment: I mean the array in the constructor. 
I initialized the array in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about what you mean by the 'original array' as you haven't provided an explanation for that, but it seems like you're having an issue where your program is analyzing a board/array that you don't want it to check.  Regardless, based on the code you provided I'm going to take a stab at it.

I think your problem may be stemming from the fact that you seem to be editing the same board that you're referencing to see whether or not an answer is correct in the first place.  I would suggest you utilize two different boards: one that is filled out to begin with with all the correct answers (and is hidden from the player), and then a second board that will be filled out by the player over the course of the game.  So in your implementation you would take the values given by the player in main and then check the filled-out 'answer' board, and then if the player's guess matches the value on the board you would enter that value into the player's board.

If this wasn't really your question I apologize and will delete my answer but as you haven't provided much background I thought I'd take a swing at it.  Hope this helps.

Comment: public SudokuPuzzle(){
        board = new int[][]{
                {1,2,3,4,9,7,8,6,5},
                {4,5,9,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {6,7,8,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {3,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
                {2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {9,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0},
                {8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                {5,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0}
        };
    }
here is my constructor. 
my problem is that if the user enters a number in this board, the method "addInitial" keep checking on the board in the constructor.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  As Erwin suggested, I think something is wrong with your conditionals.  I think you're trying to do too much in one loop.  Try breaking it up into a few loops and if statements.  The first one could check to see if the slot the player is trying fill has already been correctly guessed (it's non-zero), and *then* iterate through the row checking to see if the guess is already contained in the row, then do the same for the column in a seperate 'for' loop.  Have a boolean variable tied to each conditional/loop, and if all 3 boolean are true change the value in the table.

Comment: I think what's happening is that you're getting a false positive for one or multiple conditionals and it's resulting in nothing being changed.

Comment: Also, it's probably worth making board a static variable and initValue a static method if you haven't already done so.  It might not change anything but it's worth a shot.